# Google maps API returning No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with Node.js module

Tags: node.js, google-maps

I am using the node module `@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js` to make requests to the Google maps API. When I make requests to any of their API endpoints (e.g directions API, places API, etc), I get these errors:

```
xhr.js:125 Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"
```

```
xhr.js:125 Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"
```

```
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?
destination=Universal%20Studios%20Hollywood&key=mykey&origin=Disneyland' from 
origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
is present on the requested resource.
```

**Here are the things I've tried:**

**1.** I've tried accessing different API endpoints, (e.g instead of directions, places.)

**2.** I've tried adding headers manually, but I don't really know what headers i should add to make this work.

**3.** I have also tried accessing this API from my normal browser (Google). It returned a proper response, so it isn't an improper API key.

**Also Note:**

I have activated my API key, activated each of the APIs I want to use, and I have set up a billing account with Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Not for browser

[@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js) is not compatible with browser environments because the Google server DOES NOT return the necessary CORS headers. This package is for Nodejs.

From the readme:

[image: not for browser]

## Alternative [Preferred]

Use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview.

Your code will look similar to the following:

```
const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
const request = {
    origin: 'Disneyland',
    destination: 'Universal Studios Hollywood',
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
};
const response = await directionsService.route(request);
```

A directions [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) is available.

## Alternative 2

Proxy the directions endpoint through your own server and add CORS headers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that we have a Front End telemetry switched on (Azure Application Insights) and it was causing all requests to add additional headers, I would suggest checking if you have any service that might be including extra headers to all requests.

Due to the inclusion of "context, request-id, traceparent" in the "Access-Control-Request-Headers" of the request, the Google Maps API does not return the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the response headers.

[image]

When "context, request-id, traceparent" are not in the "Access-Control-Request-Headers", the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is returned by the Google Maps API
[image]

Answer (score -2):

are you using cors on your endpoint?
you should allow your endpoint to respond to a different origin (this is why is Cross Origin, because it is different from the location of your endpoint).

[here](https://stackabuse.com/handling-cors-with-node-js) you can find a good/simple example of using cors policy in nodejs

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't really control the endpoint, since this is Google, and don't actually have access to their stuff. I need to find a way to get around this CORS error without changing the endpoint. the node module should take care of this for me, but it unfortunately doesn't...

Comment: add headers to your request then
that Access-Control-Allow-Origin and others.
you said you can access the website via browser right? then see the request that is been made in the  network tab on devtools, there will be the headers used

Comment: reiterating that this does not work since there is no access to the server endpoint. an alternative would be to proxy the endpoint and customize headers.